# Retry policy on blob leasing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am setting a retry policy on the `CloudBlobClient`, like this:

```
// Instantiating the client with an exponential retry policy
var client = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
client.DefaultRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
    RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 3)
};

// Getting a reference to the desired blob
var blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference("leases");
var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("someblob");
```

**When acquiring a lease on a blob, will this retry policy be implicitly performed on this lease transaction?**

```
blob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), leaseId);
```

Or do I need to explicitly specify the retry policy:

```
blob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), leaseId, null, new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 3) });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When acquiring a lease on a blob, will this retry policy be implicitly
>   performed on this lease transaction?

Yes. If you take a look at the source code for [`AcquireLease`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Blob/CloudBlockBlob.cs#L3187), you will notice that the method calls [`ApplyDefaults`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Blob/BlobRequestOptions.cs#L76) method of [`BlobRequestOptions`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Blob/BlobRequestOptions.cs) class which picks the options from service client if no options are specified.

Comment: I certainly could have taken a dig into the code myself.  Thanks again, Gaurav.